# Gray-out preprocessor conditionals

Tags: faces, syntax-highlighting, c++, c

Is there a package that will gray out or hide the false portion of a c preprocessor macro?

```
#define ENABLE 1
#if ENABLE
    bool hide = false;
#else
    bool hide = true;
#endif
```

In the above example, I want `bool hide = true;` to be grayed out or hidden.

I've looked at [Hide If Def](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs?search=%22HideIfDef%22), but it doesn't produce my desired effect.  Executing `M-x hide-ifdefs` hides  `bool hide = false;`, but I would expect `bool hide = true;` to be hidden.

The functionality I am looking for would be similar to what NetBeans does.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean about `hide-ifdef-mode` having no effect? It certainly works for me. Did you run `hide-ifdefs`?

Comment: I modified my question to reflect what I am experiencing.  hide-ifdef-mode appears to only hide the #if part of #if - #else - #endif blocks.

Comment: You have to run `M-x hide-ifdefs` You didn't understand Willy's answer.

Comment: I added more clarity to my question. `M-x hide-ifdefs` will hide the correct block when I use an integer (ie 1 or 0).  But if I wrap that integer into a macro called `ENABLE` then `M-x hide-ifdefs` doesn't appear to unwrap the macro.  Instead it always hides `#if ENABLE` block.

Comment: You would have to build all of the preprocessor functionality into an elisp program: not impossible, but unlikely - I certainly don't know of any such implementation.

Comment: The [rtags](https://github.com/Andersbakken/rtags) package does this. Bare in mind that it's not easy to install and configure

Answer (score 3):

Sorry that I didn't see this earlier.  This should only happen in older hide-ifdef-mode in Emacs v24 or earlier.  For any Emacs version newer than **25.1** (released 2016/09/17), the aforementioned [Hide If Def](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/HideIfDef) that I rewrote is built-in and replace the old implementation, which did have the problem of not being able to evaluate preprocessor macros properly.  In newer Emacs, you should see something like this by performing `C-c @ h` (`M-x hide-ifdefs`):

[image]

By marking the "`ENABLE`" and press `C-c @ e` (`M-x hif-evaluate-macro`) you can see the value of `ENABLE` shown in the echo area.

However, I am not sure why [Hide If Def](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/HideIfDef) was not working at the time this question was asked (2017/3/22). Before I submitted it into Emacs source trunk (2014/07/07) it has been working for Emacs v24 or even v23. Now I can no longer access Emacs24 or 23 therefore can't reproduce the issue.  Anyway, please be sure to try newer (above v25) Emacs.

(By the way, if you really like the texts to be "grayed" out, try `C-c @ C-w` (`M-x hide-ifdef-toggle-shadowing`), then the hidden texts will really be "grayed" out.)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

'hide-ifdef-mode' hides, but it doesn't do the preprocessor evaluation, since that can come from multiple places, most of which aren't available to an Emacs mode which is just looking at a single file.

You enter `hide-ifdef-mode`, then tell the mode what things are defined and are not, using `hide-ifdef-define`/`hide-ifdef-undef`.  Then `hide-ifdefs` will do what you want. You can save lists of these definitions and toggle them (`hide-ifdef-set-define-alist`/`hide-ifdef-use-define-alist`). `hif-evaluate-macro` might be pretty valuable for you to handle more involved macrology.

It is simple to use but tedious if you have a lot of complex preprocessor defs that depend on others etc.

Might be some more project-aware packages that wrap this to make this easier, not sure.